# he Modified Principle of Mathematical Induction.

Tags: logic

Suppose that  $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy

(i) $a \in S$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$

(ii) $\operatorname{If} k \geq a, k \in S,$ then $(k+1) \in S$

then $S=\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \geq a\}$

By the way we define $\mathbb{N}$ as the intersection of all the inductive sets which contains the $1$

Im very stuck and I have no idea what to do, any hint?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is? Or what, in the end, you are supposed to have accomplished?  You just gave us the definition of S. ... OK ... so ... now what? Are you supposed to show something is true about S? And what would that be? So, before we can help you *how* you are supposed to do something ... *what* something are you supposed to do?

Comment: I only read statements, not a question. What exactly is it you're asking?

Comment: Presumably the problem is to prove the result stated in the first four lines. HINT: Consider the set $$A=\{n\in\Bbb N:n<a\text{ or }n\in S\}\,.$$

Comment: Presumably the equality sign in the alleged conclusion should be $\supseteq$, since the hypotheses don't prevent $S$ from containing natural numbers smaller than $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to show a modified version of the induction principle (since your title is the modified principle of mathematical induction).
Which states something like this: 
Let $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $a\leqslant n$ let $A(n)$ be an assertion.
Suppose: 
(i) $A(a)$ holds
(ii) For all $a\leqslant n$ be true that if $A(n)$ holds, $A(n+1)$ holds too.
Then $A(n)$ is true for all $a\leqslant n$.
To prove this variant of induction set $N:=\{n\in\mathbb{N}|A(n+a) holds \} $ and use the induction principle.